# Navbar icon not showing in some browsres

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a responsive webpage. I am using a custom navbar, as follows;

```js
      function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
        if (x.className === "topnav") {
          x.className += " responsive";
        } else {
          x.className = "topnav";
        }
      }
```

```css
/* Remove margins and padding from the list, and add a black background color */

ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10;
  padding: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
}
/* Float the list items side by side */

ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
  margin: 10;
  padding: 10;
}
/* Style the links inside the list items */

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 40px;
}
/* Change background color of links on hover */

/* ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #fff;}
    
    /* Hide the list item that contains the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */

ul.topnav li.icon {
  display: none;
}
/* When the screen is less than 680 pixels wide, hide all list items, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the list item that contains the link to open and close the topnav (li.icon) */

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens */

@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
```

```html
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <li>
    <a href="#news">
      <img class="img-responsive" width="60px" src="imagenes/botones/logo_hera.png" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#news">
      <img class="img-responsive" width="180px" src="imagenes/botones/doctores_boton.png" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#news">
      <img class="img-responsive" width="180px" src="imagenes/botones/hospitales_boton.png" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#news">
      <img class="img-responsive" width="180px" src="imagenes/botones/farmacias_boton.png" />
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#news">
      <img class="img-responsive" width="180px" src="imagenes/botones/laboratorios_boton.png" />
    </a>
  </li>

  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

On my PC and my iPhone, I can see the navbar icon as I want:

iPhone Screenshot:
[image]

But on my Android device it looks as follows:

[image]

There is no navbar icon visible.

What is wrong at my code?

EDIT:

I know the toggle icon is there, but not visible. It works when touched

Comment: try adding `!important` to the `display: inline-block;` line

Comment: @khuderm, like this:  display: inline-block !important;  ? No changes, but thank you

Comment: perhaps an issue with media screen? Just guessing here. Try testing with explicit widths and see if you find something.

Comment: @MandeepJain, thank you. I know the toggle icon is there, but not visible. It works when touched.

Comment: Ohk. please add that part to your question. Its helpful :)

Comment: I dont have access to an android device now, but if it were, I would be experimenting with right and top properties of 'ul.topnav.responsive li.icon'. Try changing to 25.

Comment: @MandeepJain, thank you, I will try it now.

Answer (score 0):

please use this code in your style sheet add

```
@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
ul.topnav li.icon {
display: block;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have given `float:rigt` to *icon* it's pushed beyond the device width in android. Adding a margin-right fixed the issue for me.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 680px)
ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10%;
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

One more invalid property I found in `ul.topnav` is margin and padding value was just plan numerical. Please use the following snippet

```
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, no changes with your proposal, I know the toggle icon is there, but not visible. It works when touched.

Comment: I live edited your URL http://herasalud.com/#news. Its working fine. Maybe clear your cache ;)

Comment: I know it works fine on most devices, but not on an 5.5 inch android mobile. On my PC, on my Mac, on my iPhone it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
@media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }

  ul.topnav li {
    float:right;
  }

  ul.topnav li.icon {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/chris2001/Lc57jw4c/1/

Not sure if it is what you want though.

Comment: Thank you, but the toggle icon is not visible on the 5.5inch android device