# Center custom navbar menu horizontally

Tags: html, css

I want to horizontally center a custom navbar menu:

```
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav" >
  <li><a href="index.html"><img class="img-responsive" width="60px" src="imagenes/botones/logo_hera.png" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="doctores.html"><img class="img-responsive" width="180px" src="imagenes/botones/doctores_boton.png" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#news"><img class="img-responsive" width="180px" src="imagenes/botones/hospitales_boton.png" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#news"><img class="img-responsive" width="180px" src="imagenes/botones/farmacias_boton.png" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#news"><img class="img-responsive" width="180px" src="imagenes/botones/laboratorios_boton.png" /></a></li>

  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
/* Remove margins and padding from the list, and add a black background color */
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;


}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.topnav li {float: left;
    margin: 10;
    padding: 10;

  }

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;

    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 40px;


}
```

But it is shown at the left side of the screen,

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Where your list is placed? Could you provide HTML context?

Comment: @nevermind it is the only content inside the <body> tags.

Comment: @mvasco you have mentioned float in li ..ul.topnav li {float: left; and if possible please provide your fiddle

Comment: @Shivkumar, yes it is right. I want the list items side by side.

Comment: @Shivkumar, I have included a screenshot. What I want is to center the complete block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that you were using float left, which while it causes the desired effect of having the list items listed in a horizontal line, it causes them to be float to the left.  Instead you should use: 'display: inline', which does the same thing but without the float to the left.

here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/chris2001/Lc57jw4c/1/ with a working answer. :)

```
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.topnav li {
  /* float: left; */
    margin: 10;
    padding: 10;
    display: inline;
   /* text-align: center; */

  }
```

Comment: Welcome. Glad I could help :)

Comment: please take a look at my other question, not answered yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40879955/navbar-icon-not-showing-in-some-browsres

Answer (score 1):

```css
/* Remove margins and padding from the list, and add a black background color */
ul.topnav {
    display: inline-table;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.links{
    text-align: center;
}    
/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.topnav li {float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;

}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
            <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav" >
          <li><a href="index.html"><img class="img-responsive" width="60px" src="imagenes/botones/logo_hera.png" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="doctores.html"><img class="img-responsive" width="180px" src="imagenes/botones/doctores_boton.png" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#news"><img class="img-responsive" width="180px" src="imagenes/botones/hospitales_boton.png" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#news"><img class="img-responsive" width="180px" src="imagenes/botones/farmacias_boton.png" /></a></li>
          <li><a href="#news"><img class="img-responsive" width="180px" src="imagenes/botones/laboratorios_boton.png" /></a></li>
          <li class="icon">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

A little modification in code. see result in full page.

Answer (score 1):

try and adjust margin and padding according to your need.
If you have any parent element for topnav then use align property.

```
ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 2% auto ; 
    padding: 15% auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: inline-block` instead of `float: left` on your link elements (`ul.topnav li`) and add `text-align: center` to your `ul.topnav` should do it.

```css
/* Remove margins and padding from the list, and add a black background color */
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.topnav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10;
  padding: 10;
}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;

  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav" >
  <li><a href="index.html"><img class="img-responsive" width="60px" src="https://dummyimage.com/60x60/000/fff" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="doctores.html"><img class="img-responsive" width="180px" src="https://dummyimage.com/180x180/000/fff" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#news"><img class="img-responsive" width="180px" src="https://dummyimage.com/180x180/000/fff" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#news"><img class="img-responsive" width="180px" src="https://dummyimage.com/180x180/000/fff" /></a></li>
  <li><a href="#news"><img class="img-responsive" width="180px" src="https://dummyimage.com/180x180/000/fff" /></a></li>

  <li class="icon">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```